# Angular md-button destroys alignment

Tags: html, css, angular

When i don't insert md-button everything works perfectly. But when I add md-button, span doesn't work properly. The number "5" goes down. How can I solve this problem?

HTML:

```
<button md-button class="special-orders">xüsusi təkliflər <span>5</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
.special-orders {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    span {
      font-size: 11px;
      display:inline-block;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FF2868;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Is that how you use the md-button ? the way i use it is
<md-button class="special-orders">xüsusi təkliflər <span>5</span></md-button>

Comment: I did what you said and it gave this error: 'md-button' is not a known element

Comment: my bad. its Angular, not AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material styling sets the line-height on the button to 36px which seems to be causing the problem with the span having a fixed height and width. Setting the line height on the span as well is easier than trying to line everything up.

```
    .special-orders {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: white;
      span {
        line-height: 18px;
        width: 18px;
        display:inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FF2868;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 0;
      }
    }
```